# What does sendmail need to specifically see in order to determine if a remote MTA supports 8-bit MIME transport?

Tags: smtp, email-server, sendmail

I'm troubleshooting an intermittent issue where some international characters appear to be malformed after going through sendmail.

I recently came across [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/sendmail,+4th+Edition/9780596510299/ch20s08s08.html) article which describes the `F=7` delivery agent flag.  Specifically, the article mentions that

> Beginning with V8.7, the F=7 delivery agent flag can be used to
>   suppress certain kinds of MIME conversions. For example, if the
>   EightBitMode option (EightBitMode on page 1025) is set to `p` (pass 8)
>   and if the message contains 8-bit MIME data in its body, this F=7
>   delivery agent flag will force sendmail to bounce the message with the
>   following SMTP error, and to exit with EX_DATAERR:

My question is: what does sendmail specifically look for to determine if the downstream MTA supports 8-bit mime?  In response to a `EHLO`, the downstream server is advertising:

```
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 200000000
250-VRFY
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 8BITMIME
```

Note that it's `250 8BITMIME` and not `250-8BITMIME` (with the dash). Would this be enough for sendmail to consider that the remote source doesn't support 8bitmime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that it's 250 8BITMIME and not 250-8BITMIME (with the dash). 
>   Would this be enough for sendmail to consider that the remote source doesn't support 8bitmime?

No. This is called *continuation* and it only signifies that the line is the last line of the SMTP reply.

And generally **8BITMIME** should be the only thing required to show that the MTA on the other side is able to handle 8 bit messages. (This is the externsion marker of the relevant RFC6152.)